# "500: Internal server error" when trying to upload a package to PyPI

Tags: python, pypi

I have been trying to upload my package on PyPI, but I got the error " Received "500: Internal server error" Package upload appears to have failed. Retry 1 of 5" which does not tell me what could be wrong.

My package can be found from:

https://github.com/hcolaux/famn_opt

I have anaconda 1.9.7 and conda 4.6.14, and I typed the commands in Anaconda Powershell Prompt:

```
setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

Note that I am using the "test.pypi.org" site to test the upload, but the regular site does not work either.

Comment: A 500 is usually an error on the server and should not be related to your data. In any case there is not much to say without the error message which should only be visible to the administrators.

Comment: you might be inside office network thats why not able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried from work and from home with the same result, so I thought it might be related to the program and not the server. I will try from somewhere else and try to contact the twine programmers.

Comment: @HcN, this sounds like a bug, can you file an issue at https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues? Please attach or include the exact distribution file you were attempting to upload as well. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try: `python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*` shouldn't change anything but you never know.

Comment: Also, make sure you authenticated properly and have an account on pypi and test pypi.

Comment: Thanks. `python3` does not help (it was indeed worth trying). I also type the username and password directly in the command prompt : `python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/* -u hcolaux -p *******`, but I would not get a 500 error in that case in the case of an identification problem, would I ?

Answer (score 0):

You need yo upload like this `python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*` and also make sure you have accounts in PyPI and test PyPI

Answer (score 0):

And another method to upload it is to create a file called `.pypi rc` and add the file should contain :

```
[disutils]
index-servers=pypi

[pypi]
repository = https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

and run `twine upload dist/*`

Comment: It's "distutils" not "disutils"

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, attempting to upload the file from Linux.

Then I attempted to upload the exact same file from Windows, using the exact same credentials - and I got a more descriptive error message, to the effect that the size of my file exceeded the limit of the test pypi server.

Also there is a --verbose option that you can try to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could check is to make sure that the produced wheel package name conforms to PEP491 (it should be since it's automatically named): https://peps.python.org/pep-0491/#file-name-convention

If it doesn't match, then the rejection is a unexpected '500' server error.